# My f8 key is an lcd screen and I want a tactile button to step into a program. Is there any way to change it to another key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

My <kbd>F8</kbd> key on my new laptop is an lcd screen and I want a tactile button to step into a program in a VBA build eviroment. Is there any way to change it to another key?

FYI, I'm writing macros for Excel as a part of Office365.

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your question is, but check out something like AutoHotKey